# Why am I getting an object reference error on my List<> object?

Tags: c#

I have a class called `StartingUserInterface` that has a list of `Teams` that is written out as so:

```
public class StartingUserInterface
{
    public List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
    public static string PlayerName;
    AddPlayer();
}
```

In a method within the same class, I am trying to add a user-specified player name to a user-specified team by first finding the team within the `Teams` list , and then setting the name of the player to that team:

```
public static void AddPlayer()
{ 
    PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
    Team team = new Team();
    team.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    team = Teams.Find(x => x.Name == team.Name);
    team.AddPlayer(PlayerName);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the `Team` class:

```
public class Team
{ 
    public string Name;

    public void AddPlayer(string name)
    {
        Player Player = new Player()
        {
            Name = name;
        };
}
```

The error message I am getting says

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'StartingUserInterface.Teams'

...when I try to set the Teams list item to the team object: `team = Teams.Find(x => x.Name == team.Name);` in the AddPlayer() method. Am I doing something obviously wrong? It seems to me that it is saying the List object doesn't exist, but I created an instance of it at the start of the class.

Comment: Why are you declaring a `Team` object, setting its `Name` property and then overwriting it? I realize you're using the value to find the actual team in the next line, but it'd be cleaner/clearer to just read directly into a string and then use *that*: `var teamName = Console.ReadLine(); Team team = Teams.Find(x=>x.Name==teamName);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use a non static field in a static method so you should make `Teams` List a static variable.

> Yours

```
public List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
```

> Changed

```
public static List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
```